# Avoid copying an array when using mexCallMATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, mex, memcpy

I have written a mex file for MATLAB. It calls MATLAB `pinv` function to calculate the Moore Penrose pseudoinverse. I named this function `my_pinv`. `my_pinv` gets an array and returns its pseudoinverse, exactly similar to `pinv`:

```
A = magic(8); A = A(:,1:6)
b = 260*ones(8,1)
x = my_pinv(A)*b
```

In the mex file, however, I have to copy the values of the input array to be able to use `mexCallMATLAB`. Here is the content of `my_pinv.cpp`:

```
#include <matrix.h>
#include <mex.h>
#include <string.h>

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    #define PRHS_A prhs[0]
    #define PLHS_X plhs[0] 

    int M = mxGetM( PRHS_A ); // Get the dimensions of  A.
    int N = mxGetN( PRHS_A );

    double *A_ptr = mxGetPr( PRHS_A );
    mxArray *PINV_A =  mxCreateDoubleMatrix(M, N,  mxREAL);  /* Put input in an mxArray */
    memcpy(mxGetPr(PINV_A), A_ptr,  sizeof(double)*M*N);

    PLHS_X = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(N, M, mxREAL);  // Create the output matrix.

    mexCallMATLAB(1, &PLHS_X, 1, &PINV_A, "pinv");

}
```

Is there anyway that I skip using `memcpy` and directly use the input array, `prhs[0]`, in `mexCallMATLAB`? I actually don't like the fact that the values of input array needs to be copied especially when the input array is very large.

In fact, I would like to be able to use something like

```
mexCallMATLAB(1, &PLHS_X, 1, &RHS_A, "pinv"); // (I know it is not right and the compiler would not like it but it is for the sake of example)
```

rather than

```
mexCallMATLAB(1, &PLHS_X, 1, &PINV_A, "pinv");
```

Could someone share his/her experiences in this regard?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`mexCallMATLAB` has the following signature:

```
int mexCallMATLAB(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs,
    mxArray *prhs[], const char *functionName);
```

For some reason, the RHS array is not marked with the `const` qualifier. I dont know why... This explains why you get a compilation error:

```
// this is from Visual C++ 2013
error C2664: 'int mexCallMATLAB(int,mxArray*[],int,mxArray *[],const char *)' :
cannot convert argument 4 from 'const mxArray *[]' to 'mxArray *[]'
    Conversion loses qualifiers
```

The solution is to explicitly cast away the constant-ness telling the compiler that we know what we're doing:

#### my_pinv.cpp

```
#include "mex.h"

void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
{
    // validate arguments
    if(nrhs != 1 || nlhs > 1)
        mexErrMsgIdAndTxt("mex:error", "Wrong number of arguments.");
    //perhaps do more validations here..

    // out = pinv(in)
    mexCallMATLAB(1, plhs, 1, const_cast<mxArray**>(prhs), "pinv");
}
```

Now in MATLAB:

```
>> x = rand(4,3);
>> my_pinv(x) - pinv(x)
ans =
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     0
```

---

If for some reason and in some corner case this proves problematic (I doubt it), the safer way is to just duplicate the array using:

```
mxArray *in = mxDuplicateArray(prhs[0]);
mexCallMATLAB(1, plhs, 1, &in, "pinv");
mxDestroyArray(in);
```

If you absolutely want to avoid creating a deep copy, there are [undocumented functions](http://www.mk.tu-berlin.de/Members/Benjamin/mex_sharedArrays) that create a shared-data copy (where only a new array header is created, but the data is shared).

Comment: 3 seconds from posting mine. :) +1  BTW, _how the heck_ can I get notifications more frequently than 15 minutes (actually much longer)?

Comment: It isn't clear whether `mexCallMATLAB` frees the matrices passed in.  One way or another, your version with `const_cast` will have a different use count from the code in the question.

Comment: yes, the description of `mexCallMATLAB` says: "`MATLAB allocates dynamic memory to store the mxArrays in plhs. MATLAB automatically deallocates the dynamic memory when you clear the MEX-file`". However the `plhs` of the gatway MEX function (not to be confused with `plhs` argument of `mexCallMATLAB`) is a special case, where if you assign an array into to it, it is removed from the list of things to be automatically free. This is not exactly documented, but I read it somewhere (most likely from a post by *James Tursa*)

Answer (score 2):

Casting away the const to input `prhs` directly to `mexCallMATLAB` as Amro already said is how to handle this most efficiently.  Although the declaration for `mexCallMATLAB` certainly does not guarantee that the input array will not be modified (declared as `mxArray *prhs[]`), if the function you call is well behaved and follows the stern advice of MathWorks never to modify the right hand side arguments, this is not a problem.

Regarding the allocation of `plhs` by `mexCallMATLAB`, this is done just like any other MATLAB function.  There is no difference if you do:

```
% in MATLAB
x = pinv(A);
```

or

```
% in MEX
mxArray *x;  % no mxArray allocated, just a pointer
mexCallMATLAB(1, &x, 1, const_cast<mxArray**>(prhs), "pinv");  % pinv creates *x
```

`mexCallMATLAB` (or rather `pinv`) creates the output array.  **Don't waste time creating the left hand side.**  If this bothers you, create an empty `mxArrary`:

```
mxArray *x = mxCreateDoubleMatrix(0, 0, mxREAL); % but not necessary
```

`pinv` will wipe it out and make a new one, just as if you had done this in MATLAB:

```
x = [];
x = pinv(A);
```

**Either way, the MATLAB memory manager owns the array.**  It will not evaporate when the MEX function returns or is cleared from memory.

From [Memory Management Issues](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/memory-management-issues.html) at MathWorks:

> When a MEX-file returns control to MATLAB®, it returns the results of its computations in the output arguments—the mxArrays contained in the left-side arguments plhs[]. MATLAB destroys any mxArray created by the MEX-file that is not in this argument list.
>
> However, do not destroy an mxArray in a source MEX-file when it is:
>   * passed to the MEX-file in the right-hand side list prhs[]
>    * **returned in the left side list plhs[]**
>    * returned by mexGetVariablePtr
>    * used to create a structure

Comment: +1 ah good find, it is documented after all (the fact that `plhs` assigned by `mexCallMATLAB` wont be freed on exit) :)