# MATLAB mexCallMatlab causes crash

Tags: c, matlab, mex, sliding-window

I'm trying to develop a function in mex. The aim of the function should be sliding a window onto a 3D image and apply some function inside the window. Currently I'm stuck because when the algorithm reaches the call at the `padarray` function, MATLAB crashes.

So far I wrote these lines of code

```
#include <iostream>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"       

using namespace std;

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
    #define O_IMAGE       plhs[0]
    #define I_IMAGE       prhs[0]
    #define I_PADSIZE     prhs[1]
    #define I_FUN         prhs[2]
    #define I_OPTION      prhs[3]

  // Argument Checking:
  if(nrhs < 1 || nrhs > 4) /* Check the number of arguments */
    mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of input arguments.");
  else if(nlhs > 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments.");

  // Variable declarations
  static const char padding[] = "symmetric";
  const char *windowShape;
  const mwSize *dim;
  mwSize *dimPad;
  mwSize ndim;
  double *pad, *windowSize, *thetaStep, *phiStep;
  mxArray *inputFun[4], *inputPadFun[3], *input_image, *imagePad, *output_image;

  /*Get dimensions of input image*/
  ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(I_IMAGE);
  dim = mxGetDimensions(I_IMAGE);

  /* Create dimensions of padded image*/
  dimPad = (mwSize *) mxCalloc(ndim, sizeof(mwSize));
  dimPad = (mwSize *) memcpy((void *) dimPad,(void *) dim, ndim*sizeof(mwSize));
  pad = mxGetPr(I_PADSIZE);
  for (int i=0;i<ndim;++i)
  {
      dimPad[i] += 2*pad[i];
  }

  /*Get pointer to the input image*/
  input_image = (mxArray *) mxGetData(I_IMAGE);

  /* Create output image*/
  O_IMAGE = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim, dim, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
  output_image = (mxArray *) mxGetData(O_IMAGE);

  /* Create padded image*/
  imagePad = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim, dimPad, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);

  // Padding input matrix
  inputPadFun[0] = input_image;
  inputPadFun[1] = (mxArray *)(pad);
  inputPadFun[2] = (mxArray *)(padding);
  mexCallMATLAB(1, &imagePad, 3, inputPadFun, "padarray");

  // Clean UP
  mxFree(dimPad);
  mxDestroyArray(imagePad);
}
```

I checked the dimensions of the images in input and in output at `mexCallMATLAB` and they appear to be correct. I don't really understand what I'm doing wrong. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I generally have Matlab chrash with mex files when I was doing wrong memory stuff. Check that you create `imagePad` properly.

Comment: Thank you for your advice. How can I check that the memory is allocated correctly? I checked that the dimensions are correct and both `dim` and `dimPad` have the expected values. I don't use `imagePad` before calling the function, thus I don't understand how I can do something wrong with the memory.

Comment: If `imagePad` is not big enough to store the padded array, then you have memory access error!

Comment: I checked and `ndim = 3` and is okay and `dimPad = [42 42 42]` also this is okay because the original image is `32x32x32` and the padding array is `5x5x5`.

Comment: I dont know. Check datatypes of inputs and outputs. I have no idea what it could be else.

Comment: I think there's something iffy with your `padding` string.  Try using `mxCreateString` instead of casting `padding` to a pointer to `mxArray` for the third argument of `inputPadFun`.  You also don't need to cast `pad`.  That's already a `mxArray` pointer, so just do `prhs[1]` or `I_PADSIZE`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several problematic casts.

Since `pad` is a `double*`, you are doing a nonsensical cast here:

```
(mxArray *)(pad)
```

Similarly for `padding` which is a `const char[]`, you can't do

```
(mxArray *)(padding)
```

In the following line, `mxGetData` returns a `void*` to the buffer with underlying data of a **primitive type** (`double`, `single`, etc.), but you are casting it to an `mxArray*`:

```
(mxArray *) mxGetData(prhs[0]);
```

Remember that `mxArray` is opaque object type defined by MathWorks and you must use their functions to create these objects.  Also you can only handle pointers to them.

There are other problems...

---

**Code**

Here's a C++ example of how you might change your code:

```
// padarray_BugsFree.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "mex.h"
#include "matrix.h"       

void mexFunction(int nlhs,mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[]) {
  if(nrhs != 2)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Wrong number of input arguments:\n\t"
            "Iout = padarray_BugsFree(I,pad)");
  if(nlhs > 1)
    mexErrMsgTxt("Too many output arguments:\n\t"
            "Iout = padarray_BugsFree(I,pad)");

  if(!(mxIsDouble(prhs[0]) && mxIsDouble(prhs[1])))
      mexErrMsgTxt("Inputs must be double");

  mwSize ndim = mxGetNumberOfDimensions(prhs[0]);
  const mwSize *dim = mxGetDimensions(prhs[0]);

  if (ndim != mxGetNumberOfElements(prhs[1]))
      mexErrMsgTxt("pad must be equal to ndims(I)");

  const double *pad = mxGetPr(prhs[1]);
  mwSize *dimPad = (mwSize *) mxCalloc(ndim, sizeof(mwSize));
  for (int i=0; i<ndim; ++i) {
      dimPad[i] = dim[i] + 2*pad[i];
  }

  mxArray *imagePad = mxCreateNumericArray(ndim, dimPad, mxDOUBLE_CLASS, mxREAL);
  mxFree(dimPad);

  // Padding input matrix
  mxArray *padding = mxCreateString("symmetric");
  mxArray *inputPadFun[3];
  inputPadFun[0] = const_cast<mxArray*>(prhs[0]);
  inputPadFun[1] = const_cast<mxArray*>(prhs[1]);
  inputPadFun[2] = padding;
  mexCallMATLAB(1, &imagePad, 3, inputPadFun, "padarray");
  mxDestroyArray(padding);

  // do something with the padded image and generate output
  plhs[0] = mxDuplicateArray(imagePad); // in place of useful operations
  mxDestroyArray(imagePad);
}
```

**Demo**

```
>> I = magic(3)
I =
     8     1     6
     3     5     7
     4     9     2
>> pad = [2 2]
pad =
     2     2
>> padarray_BugsFree
Error using padarray_BugsFree
Wrong number of input arguments:
    Iout = padarray_BugsFree(I,pad) 
>> Iout = padarray_BugsFree(I,pad)
Iout =
     5     3     3     5     7     7     5
     1     8     8     1     6     6     1
     1     8     8     1     6     6     1
     5     3     3     5     7     7     5
     9     4     4     9     2     2     9
     9     4     4     9     2     2     9
     5     3     3     5     7     7     5
```

**Notes**

Use the following posts as reference for how to use `mexCallMATLAB`:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/26620639/2778484
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32061007/2778484

You could also build the RHS input array as follows:

```
mxArray *inputPadFun[] = {const_cast<mxArray*>(prhs[0]),
                          const_cast<mxArray*>(prhs[1]), padding};
mexCallMATLAB(1, &imagePad, 3, inputPadFun, "padarray");
```

Comment: Beautiful :D. So what I suspected about the casting is indeed correct.

Comment: Thank you very much. Tomorrow I'll try your solution but surely it'll work and I'll accept it. Let me check if I understood correctly: if I have primitive types, I can't cast them to `mxArray *` to create an `mxArray *` but I need to use the specific function of matlab?

Comment: @BugsFree Right.  You generally can't cast (in a meaningful way) between pointers, except for `void*`.  For example, casting a `double` to a `single` is fine, but casting a `double*` to a `single*` is meaningless.

Comment: @rayryeng yes indeed.  There's a lot of funky casting going on here.  :)